# Is it possible to use this.fieldname in a constructor to initialize a field in a base class?

Tags: inheritance, dart, polymorphism

The following code isn't valid, because `this.base1` cannot be initialized from the constructor of a class that extends `BaseClass`:

```
abstract class BaseClass{
  String base1;
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass{
  int i1;
  MyClass(this.base1, this.i1);
}
```

One must do either

```
abstract class BaseClass{
  String base1;
  BaseClass(this.base1);
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass{
  int i1;  
  MyClass(String base1, this.i1) : super(base1);
}
```

or

```
abstract class BaseClass{
  String base1;
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass{
  int i1;  
  MyClass(String base1, this.i1){
    this.base1 = base1; 
  }
}
```

Using a `mixin` instead of an abstract base class won't let me do this either. However, I found that there is one way - by redeclaring the field in the implementing class:

```
abstract class BaseClass{
  String base1;
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass{
  String base1;
  int i1;  
  MyClass(this.base1, this.i1);
}
```

Is this standard practice, or are there any pitfalls one should be aware of when doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not redeclaring the parent variable in the child `MyClass`, you are creating a new one. They have the same name, but there are now two separate variables.

```
abstract class BaseClass{
  String base1;
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass{
  String base1;
  MyClass(this.base1){
    super.base1 = "A";
  }
  
  void foo(){
    print(base1 + " | " + super.base1);
  }
}


main(){
  (MyClass("B")).foo();
}
```

Result:

```
B | A
```

Aside from that, if it were possible, it would be rather fragile to any changes to either class.

For now I would stick with your first given example. If you are really concerned about the boilerplate constructor, I am not following it closely but some work is being done on default constructors in dart to potentially allow for the elimination of constructors which could be easily inferred from a simple class like that. You could search for the github issue if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `super.base1` != `this.base1`! I actually thought I had tested it and confirmed the opposite, but it turned out I was testing it using `super.toString()`, implemented as `toString() => base1`. But it turns out that _that_ `base1` refers to the subclass (which I kind of vaguely remember wrestling with in some other language many years ago as well). I'll just stick to the explicit super-initializer to save myself a whole lot of headaches in the future...

Answer (score 1):

I think redeclaring is fairly common, although you should enable the `annotate_overrides` analysis option and use `@override` so that the analyzer can detect if the name in the base class changes.

Note that redeclaring creates a new variable that overrides corresponding getter and setter in the base class.  If you like, you also could just declare a getter and setter in the abstract base class and rely on implementations to provide the data member.